# how control scrolling and zooming events in Android?

Tags: android, events, webview, scroll, zooming

I have a webview with transparent background color. this webview is upon an intent. I need to to move webview and intent both in scrolling and zooming events. if I want to say in another way, just imagine my intent is replaced by an image for example and an webview is upon image. webview has some texts, but i need to able to scroll and zoom image too. How to recognize these events from webview and pass to image behind my webview?

I am very new in android, ynx

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling add ScrollView to relativeLayout. and then add WebView to ScrollView..
For example

```
LayoutParams mp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
setContentView(rl, mp);
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
rl.addView(scroll, mp);
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
scrollView.addView(wv, mp);   
scrollView.setText("asfsdfsd")
```